# Restlet get remaining path when Router uses MODE_STARTS_WITH

Tags: java, restlet

I am creating a [Restlet](https://restlet.com/) based service that matches an incoming request with a specific initial path. In the ServerResource that handles match I want access to the remaining path.

```
Router parentRouter;
parentRouter.attach("/svc/", new MyService());
parentRouter.attach("/svc/1.0/", new MyService());
```

---

```
public class MyService extends Router
{
  public MetricsService()
  {
    attach("/m/", MyResource.class).setMatchingMode(Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
  }
}
```

---

```
public class MyResource extends ServerResource 
{
  @Override
  protected void doInit() throws ResourceException
  {
     String remainingPath = ???   <-- how do I do this?
  }
  @Get
  protected void doit() throws ResourceException
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now for example the following requests result in the following remaining paths:

```
http://localhost/svc/m/                  -->  ""
http://localhost/svc/m/a                 -->  "a"
http://localhost/svc/v1.0/m/some/m/path  --> "some/m/path"
```

Of course there are always workarounds to get this fixed, but there is likely a more elegant of retrieving this using the existing Restlet framework. Specifically since Routers are already aware of remaining paths.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling i found the answer:

```
@Override
protected void doInit() throws ResourceException
{
   String remainingPath = getReference().getRemainingPart();
}
```